# Laravel voting system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am implementing a voting system in my laravel school project, it will be an online school platform where students can upload projects and other students can vote on the published content.

Somehow what I have done isn't working... Here is my code so far, hope someone can help me, and maybe help me on the way how to show the number of votes on a project.

This is my database migration:

```
Schema::create('votes', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
});
```

My Model:

```
Class Vote extends Eloquent{

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}

}
```

My view:

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
    <li class="medium-4 columns">
        <div class="canvas-medium">
            <img src="{{ $project->image }}">
        </div>
        <p class="title">{{ $project->name }}</p>
        <p class="owner">By 
            <a href="profile/{{ $project->user_id }}">{{ $project->user->firstname }} {{ $project->user->name }}</a>
            <a href="/vote/{{ $project->id }}">Vote</a>
        </p>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

My controller:

```
class VoteController extends BaseController{

    public function vote($id){
        $vote = new Vote;
        $vote->user_id = Auth::id();
        $vote->project_id = $id;
        $vote->Save();

        return Redirect::to('/projects');
    }

}
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@showall');
Route::get('/projects/vote/{id}', 'VoteController@vote');
```

Comment: "Somehow what I have done isn't working..." Ok, what exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors? Let's get some specifics!

Comment: When I click on the vote link, it takes me to /vote/1 for ex. and shows the error "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
<a href="/vote/{{ $project->id }}">Vote</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/projects/vote/{{ $project->id }}">Vote</a>
```

p.s. if you have no validation in place and if you didn't setup a *unique index* in database with project id and user id, a student can vote multiple times for one particular project.... which you probably you won't want perhaps?

## Edit (using fluent query builder)

`Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@showall');` will show all projects.

if you want to get the detail for each of the project, you will have to do:

- set up a route. e.g. `Route::get('/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@showone')`
- then retrieve the result in the controller/repo/model
  `return DB::table('vote')->where('project_id','=',$id)->get();`

if you want to show each vote count for every project, then it will be little bit complicated but here's this.

```
return DB::table('project AS p')->select([DB::raw('@project:=p.id'), 
       DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM votes AS v WHERE v.project_id = @project) AS votes'),
       ])->paginate(30); //or get()
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Yeah, but I was first trying to make this work.. I want a user to be able to vote only once. Do you also know how I can show all votes on a project?

Comment: i don't use eloquent. so don't know how it will be there. in query builder it is simple. `return DB::tables('votes')->where('project_id','=',$id)->count();`

Comment: How do you get the $id from the view?

Answer (score 1):

I would eschew adding the link by route, and link it by controller instead:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('VoteController@vote', [$project->id]) }}">Vote</a>
```

When viewing the page, the URL will appear as "http://example.com/projects/vote/1", for example. Also, if you change your route as follows:

- **OLD**: `/projects/vote/{id}`
- **NEW**: `/projects/{id}/vote`

Your link will be automatically changed to use the new route to that controller.

Comment: Also we can use "invokable" controller, for example "StoreVote". https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#single-action-controllers

Comment: @Ostap34PHP You certainly can at this point; you just couldn't in Laravel 4.2 in 2014 :)

Comment: oh yes)) its old question :)